# highchart updating plotOptions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a requirement where I need to change connectNulls back and forth on a highchart.

unfortunately `chart.options.plotOptions.series.update({ connectNulls: true });`

results in

> (index):73 Uncaught TypeError: chart.options.plotOptions.series.update
>   is not a function
>       at (index):73

here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/d5dbt221/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accessing elements that does not exist.

To set a single series to `connectNulls` you can do this(where 0 is the series index):

```
chart.series[0].update({ connectNulls: true});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/d5dbt221/9/

Or alternatively, if want to set all series:

```
chart.update({ plotOptions: { series: {connectNulls: true }}});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/d5dbt221/11/